# ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 0 for '{{node Conv2D_5}} , tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i want to build a convolutional_model that has the following architcuture :
CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> CONV2D -> RELU -> MAXPOOL -> FLATTEN -> DENSE
Arguments:
input_img -- input dataset, of shape (input_shape)

```
Returns:
model -- TF Keras model (object containing the information for the entire training process)
```

so here is the code that i did so far:

```
def convolutional_model(input_shape):

    input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    ## CONV2D: 8 filters 4x4, stride of 1, padding 'SAME'
    Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_img,filters=8 ,strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    ## RELU
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
    ## MAXPOOL: window 8x8, stride 8, padding 'SAME'
    P1 = tf.nn.max_pool(A1, ksize = [1, 8, 8, 1], strides = [1, 8, 8, 1], padding='SAME')
    ## CONV2D: 16 filters 2x2, stride 1, padding 'SAME'
    Z2 = tf.nn.conv2d(P1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    ## RELU
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)
    ## MAXPOOL: window 4x4, stride 4, padding 'SAME'
    P2 = tf.nn.max_pool(A2, ksize = [1, 4, 4, 1], strides = [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
    ## FLATTEN
    F = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(P2)
    ## Dense layer
    ## 6 neurons in output layer. Hint: one of the arguments should be "activation='softmax'" 
    outputs = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P, 6, activation_fn='softmax')

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=outputs)
    return model
```

i m getting the following error :

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 0 for '{{node Conv2D_5}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](input_10, Conv2D_5/filter)' with input shapes: [?,64,64,3], [].
```

can someone help pls ?
if there are any other mistakes in my code pls comment on them , I have been struggling so much with this assignment on Coursera Deeplearning spec course

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.Input(shape=(...))` creates a symbolic tensor which allows us to create model just by knowing the inputs and outputs of the model. So it is a placeholder for a tensor (but itself not a tensor).
`tf.nn.conv2d(input)` performs a convolution on the given input. Its not a model layer(not trainable), only a function. So when provided a symbolic tensor ( a placeholder) to `tf.nn.conv2d()` as input, it throws as error.

If you are trying to build a model, use `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D()`.

see tensorflow documentation for `tf.keras.Input` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input

see tensorflow documentation for `tf.nn.conv2d`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d

Answer (score 0):

```
Z1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 8,kernel_size= (4,4), strides=(1,1), padding='SAME')(input_img)
## RELU
A1 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(Z1)
## MAXPOOL: window 8x8, stride 8, padding 'SAME'
P1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8,8), strides =(8,8), padding='SAME')(A1)
## CONV2D: 16 filters 2x2, stride 1, padding 'SAME'
Z2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 16,kernel_size= (2,2),strides =(1,1), padding='SAME')(P1)
## RELU
A2 = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(Z2)
## MAXPOOL: window 4x4, stride 4, padding 'SAME'
P2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(4,4), strides =(4,4), padding='SAME')(A2)
## FLATTEN
F = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(P2)
## Dense layer
## 6 neurons in output layer. Hint: one of the arguments should be "activation='softmax'" 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, activation = 'softmax')(F)
```

It is working you can try it.